# Gmail won't send to a specific address

Tags: gmail

Gmail won't send to a real address; what can I do about it?

I get the error below (numbers are changed to #, letters changed to X):

> The address "######@xxxx.xxxxxxx.lg.jp" in the "To" field was not recognised. Please make sure that all addresses are properly formed.

Answer (score 1):

Use another email system to send a message to webmaster@xxxx.xxxxxxx.lg.jp, explaining that Gmail doesn't like their addresses, and asking if they have any aliases set up which can be used as To addresses.